# Execution timeout expired , in SQL Server, running a stored procedure results in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, backend in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, sqlexception

A stored procedure in SQL Server results in an error

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException"

The stored procedure is called from a backed ASP.NET Core 6 Web API.

Details of the exception :

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
> HResult=0x80131904
> Message=Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
> Operation cancelled by user.
> The statement has been terminated.
> Source=Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider
> StackTrace:
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalEndExecuteNonQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean isInternal, String endMethod)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryInternal(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.d__15.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.d__15.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.d__15.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.d__13.MoveNext()
> at Egen.Repository.Repositories.Attendance.AttendanceRepository.d__2.MoveNext() in
>
> Inner Exception 1:
> Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out.

What I have done: after changing the timeout the error has not occurred.

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
{
    this.Database.SetCommandTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
}
```

Stored procedure brief: I am providing brief of the stored procedure below.

```
 WHILE @AttendanceProcessedOn <= @CurrentDateMark
 BEGIN
     -- operations 
   
     SET @AttendanceProcessedOn = DATEADD(DAY, 1 , @AttendanceProcessedOn);
 END
```

I would like to know if "changing the timeout" is the right approach / best practice to solve this issue? What can be the other options to mitigate this issue?

Comment: Add missing indexes

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what's going on inside the stored procedure, but "make it more efficient." e.g.: if you're using any iterative code (e.g.: WHILE loops and/or CURSORs) start by replacing it with set-based code.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for your suggestions. I have added the brief of the store procedure in the questing post now.
As I mentioned, changing the "timeout" helped me not to get the error. My query is whether this is the right approach or not? and what can be the other ways to resolve above issue.
You have mentioned some : "make it more efficient" and "add missing indexes".

Comment: Well we can't "make more efficient" something that we can't see. How about you show us the *actual* SQL code, along with tables and indexes?

Comment: @Charlieface My query is about this "I like to know if "changing the timeout" is the right approach / best practice to solve this issue? What can be the other options to mitigate this issue?".
Brief of the store procedure is provided.

Comment: No changing the timeout isn't, that's just going to mask the problem. You almost certainly need to improve efficiency of the queries, but we have no info on that to go on. We need the *full* code for the procedure, the tables *and index* definitions, and please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com.

Comment: @ErikEJ Thanks for your suggestion. I went through some reading to know about indexing. It seems fascinating. I am excited to learn more about indexing and try to optimize the store procedure using it.

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for sharing this beautiful resource  [pastetheplan.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) . Unfortunately, I am not able to share details of the production query. I really appreciate you for your kind approach to help. I have taken note on some suggestion, I will try to utilize them to optimize the process.

Comment: You can obfuscate the plan before uploading it using SentryOne Plan Explorer, or manually. We need the query plan otherwise we can't advise.

Comment: @Charlieface 
I appreciate your continuous sharing of valuable resources. Your resourcefulness is truly noteworthy.

Comment: @Charlieface , I am attaching the [query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkuMs5EH6) . Looking forward to helpful responses.

Comment: OK that's way too big for us to fully diagnose, you need a proper consultant to go through that and optimize it. Here' some things I can see at a glance: Don't use your `TrimTime` function, it's terrible, instead just do `CAST(CAST(YourDateTime AS date) AS datetime)`. Don't use even that inside joins or `WHERE` conditions, instead use date intervals, eg `join [Cmn].[HolidayCalendar] c on c.HolidayDate >= @CurrentDate AND c.HolidayDate < DATEADD(day, 1, @CurrentDate)`. Don't use `DISTINCT`, instead work out why you are getting duplicates, perhaps you need to improve join conditions etc.....

Comment: .... Instead of doing this giant loop (I can't even see the end of it or how it loops), just do all dates in one go. Remove all usage of User Defined Functions generally, wherever you can, as they have serious performance issues. `Attendance` and `MachineData` tables need better indexing, there are index scans all over the place.

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you for the suggestions. I appreciate your insights. I plan to implement the recommendations you provided. Regarding the indexing in the Attendance and MachineData tables, do you have any specific suggestions?